# Make Outlook not show message header as default

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-client, headers

I need to hide the mail header as default to get more space for mail content.

I tried searching with [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=make+outlook+don't+show+message+header+as+default&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) and got nothing helpful.

I found out that I can toggle showing/hiding the mail header by using [Message/Move/Actions/Other Action/Message Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPwRp.png). Then, my mail would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4quZ0.png), with mail content and a compact header to give us more space to read mail.

**But I can't find any way to make this view style default**.

---

I don't agree with MadBoy, my outlook 2010 still show header even I've close it just before.

Comment: When I select Message/Move/Actions/Other Action/Message Header and close the email and open new one the setting is preserved.. and there's no message header (Outlook 2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MadBoy had said:

Message ribbon tab > Actions > Other actions > Message header

[image]